# Is there a way to code complete a null check in java within netbeans IDE?

Tags: java, netbeans, autocomplete, isnull

In Netbeans you can do stuff like writing "psvm" then pressing tab and it generates

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     //your cursor is placed here.
 }
```

Similarly there is way to write for cycles, try catch blocks, instanceof checks and stuff like that. Is there anything resembling this approach, to generate a null-check of a variable?

I would like something like this:

```
ResultSet rs;
rs //pressing some magic button like ctrl+space or "rs null<TAB>" 
   //and a code like this would be generated:

if (rs != null) //your cursor will be placed here.
```

or

```
if (rs != null)
{
    //your cursor here
}
```

Comment: Yeah, go through the preferences, there's a place where you can write your own autocomplete stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I started to dig in, should have done earlier. Don't know how to use the language to write it yet, but as soon as I'll figure it out, I'll write it and write it in the answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own template for that:

Go to tools->options->Editor->Code templates->New->Abbreviation: ifnn

Expanded text:

```
if (${EXP instanceof=”Object”} != null) {
    ${selection}${cursor}
}
```

Then press "ifnn"+TAB in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

So I decided to create this template: (A modified version of the accepted answer.)

```
if(${EXP instanceof="Object"} != null) {
    ${EXP}.${cursor}
}
```

assigned to just "nn" standing for "not null".

And also this to validate attributes/parameters at the beginning of methods.

```
Validate.notNull(${var}, "${var} can't be null");
```

which I extend by writing "valp" and pressing tab (abbreviation for validate parameter).
It is shorter and more concise than:

```
if(someVar == null){
    throw new Exception("someVar can't be null");
}
```

which is useful, when there are many validated parameters.